# Ruby Nested Hash Merge

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, hash

Given something like this:

```rb
hey = {
  some_key: {
      type: :object,
      properties: {
        id: { type: :string, example: '123', description: 'Id' },
        created_at: { type: :string, example: '2019-02-14 14:13:55'},
        updated_at: { type: :string, example: '2019-02-14 14:13:55'},
        type: { type: :string, example: 'something', description: 'Resource type' },
        token: { type: :string, example: 'token', description: 'Some description of token' }
      }
    }
}
```

I would like to go through all keys until I find one named `properties`, then mutate its content such that the keys become the value of a `description` key if it doesn't exit in its nested hash.

So for the example above, the hash would end up like this:

```rb
hey = {
  some_key: {
      type: :object,
      properties: {
        id: { type: :string, example: '123', description: 'Id' },
        created_at: { type: :string, example: '2019-02-14 14:13:55', description: 'Created At'},
        updated_at: { type: :string, example: '2019-02-14 14:13:55', description: 'Updated At'},
        type: { type: :string, example: 'something', description: 'Resource type' },
        token: { type: :string, example: 'token', description: 'Some description of token' }
      }
    }
}
```

`created_at` and `updated_at` didn't have a description.

It should also handle if `token`, for instance, had a `properties` property.

I came up with a solution that works but I am really curious on how I can improve it?

My solution below:

```
def add_descriptions(hash)
  return unless hash.is_a?(Hash)
  hash.each_pair do |key, value|
    if key == :properties
      value.each do |attr, props|
        if props[:description].nil?
          props.merge!(description: attr.to_s)
        end
      end
    end
    add_descriptions(value)
  end
end
```

Comment: Shameless plug: I have built the gem [`iteraptor`](https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor) to serve exactly this purpose.

Comment: Just hit that "edit" button. You can remove your comment after doing so and I'll do the same.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand all you know about the hash `hey` is that it is comprised of nested hashes.

```
def recurse(h)
  if h.key?(:properties)
    h[:properties].each do |k,g|
      g[:description] = k.to_s.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ') unless
        g.key?(:description)
    end
  else
    h.find { |k,obj| recurse(obj) if obj.is_a?(Hash) }
  end
end
```

```
recurse hey
  #=> {:id=>{:type=>:string, :example=>"123", :description=>"Id"},
  #    :created_at=>{:type=>:string, :example=>"2019-02-14 14:13:55",
  #      :description=>"Created At"},
  #    :updated_at=>{:type=>:string, :example=>"2019-02-14 14:13:55",
  #    :description=>"Updated At"},
  #    :type=>{:type=>:string, :example=>"something",
  #      :description=>"Resource type"},
  #    :token=>{:type=>:string, :example=>"token",
  #      :description=>"Some description of token"}}
```

The return value is the updated value of `hey`.

Comment: From what I gather from the question, the location of `:properties` within the hash will not be known before hand. Therefore, it can't be guaranteed that we can get to `:properties` via `hey[:some_key]`.

Comment: the previous commenter is right, the thing is `:properties` could be anywhere in the hash, nested as many levels as you can imagine... and inside of it the magic would happen :). Here is a repl.it with the example code I posted https://repl.it/@chdezmar/Nested-hash-merge

Comment: @user3574603, I see you are correct, so I edited my code. I was glad to see my understand was wrong as it is now a more interesting question.